# How to identify known encryption algorithm?

Tags: ida, encryption, encodings

I reverse an `.exe` file with IDA.

I see a function that appears to be encrypting something by generating some random numbers.

It there any tool to identify if it is a known encryption algorithm?

Comment: Not entirely related but you might find [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/13475/2147) useful

Comment: I tool that can do this is peid. It searches for common magic values used in algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

[Signsrch](http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm) is a somewhat old tool that searches for signatures and magic values for different encryption and hash algorithms. I had a collection of  other similar tools in the past, so I believe you can find other related tools by googling for a while.

There's a IDA plugin re-implementation of the same plugin [here](https://github.com/nihilus/IDA_Signsrch), you may wanna use it instead.

Comment: Thank you, I not understand how to install the ida plugin? `Copy the plug-in and signsrch.xml file to your IDA Pro "plugins" directory.`  witch file do I need to copt?  I saw there source file.