# How to install ida plugin to identify encryption function

Tags: ida, encryption, ida-plugin, plugin

I saw here [How to identify known encryption algorithm?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18673/how-to-identify-known-encryption-algorithm) the IDA  plugin  https://github.com/nihilus/IDA_Signsrch

I don't understand how to install it .

In the INSTALL I saw `coppy the plug-in and signsrch.xml file to your IDA Pro "plugins" directory`   .

I saw `signsrch.xml` file but I not found what is the `plug-in` that I neet to copy too.

that source file ,.

please help me to install this plugin

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile the plugin using the IDA SDK, which should result in a binary which you can then copy to the plugins directory.     Possibly the original project on sourceforge provided precompiled binaries but they don’t seem to be present on the GitHub mirror.

Comment: how do I compile that with IDA SDK? and why should I do that? why they not give compile file that I only need to copy them?   I don't found compile file on sourceforge too

Comment: nobody is obliged to give you anything, if you want to use it it’s up to you to find a way or ask/pay someone to do it for you.

Comment: @ffdebugger as an IDA Pro customer you will have gotten the credentials to download the latest IDA SDK at the time of your last download. With active maintenance you could simply request a renewal (even if it means staying on the same version). Having that SDK will then enable you - with the help of any of the supported debuggers - to build the plugin for IDA versions supported by said SDK. If you're using the freeware IDA version you'll be out of luck, though, since that doesn't support extensions (not without jumping through some hoops).